# Bash last command - skip identical commands in history

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

By using the arrow keys one can fill the command line with the last called commands. However, Bash does call all the previous commands, not just unique commands.

```
$./a.out       //oldest command called
$ gcc main.c
$ gcc main.c
$ gcc main.c   //latest command called
$              //4 strokes required to call ./a.out, altough 2 would be sufficient
```

Is there a way to ignore past commands in the history list if they are identical and automatically call/fill in the next unique command in history?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can control how commands are saved in the history with the shell variable HISTCONTROL, all you have to do is put the line

```
HISTCONTROL=erasedups
```

in your .bashrc. (I prefer erasedups over ignoredups, as it places the last command I typed always on top of the history. This way I don't have to look when I want to repeat the last command I typed.)

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for and works like a charm!